# Alternate approach to a congurence problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that positive integer $n$ of form $7k+1$, $7k+2$, $7k+5$ are the only possible solutions which satisfy that $n^5 + 4n^4 + 3n^3 = 7z+1$ for some positive integer $z$ ?

> My approach was taking n to be of $7k+1, 7k+2, \dots, 7k+6$ and then checking modulo $7$, if it was giving $1$ or not, which proves it, but is there a better approach to it?

Comment: Well you could factor your polynomial to see that $n^5+4n^4+3n^3-1\equiv (n+2)(n+5)(n+6)(n^2+5n+5)\pmod 7$ where the quadratic is irreducible...but I don't think this is easier than just checking the $7$ possible residues, each in turn.

Comment: That factorsing is pretty nice . But yeah as you said same time taking  okay

Comment: It's pretty much the same process.  Your quintic is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, so no help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way: $ $ by lil Fermat,$\bmod 7\!:\ n\not\equiv 0\Rightarrow n^6\equiv 1\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{n^3}\equiv \pm1,\,$  which we can use as a rewrite rule to reduce our *quintic* $f(n)$ to a congruent *quadratic*, viz.

$\begin{align} &{\rm Case}\ \ \ \ \:\!\color{#c00}{n^3}\equiv \,1\!:\ \  \ \ \  \overbrace{f(n)\equiv\, n^2\!\color{#0a0}{-\!3}n\!+\!2}^{\textstyle f(n)=\! (n^2\!\color{#0a0}{+\!4}n\!+\!3)\color{#c00}{n^3}{-1}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}\equiv (n\!-\!2)(n\!-\!1)\equiv 0\iff \color{#90f}{n\equiv 2,1}\\[.3em]
&{\rm Case}\ \ \color{#c00}{n^3}\equiv -1\!:\ \ {-}f(n)\equiv\:\! n^2\!+\!4n\!+\!4\equiv\, (n\!+\!2)^2\equiv 0\iff \color{#90f}{n\equiv -2\equiv 5} \end{align}$